# How to capture audio by PyAV in Linux?

Tags: python, audio, alsa, pyav, aiortc

I want to capture audio to stream in with aiortc, installed on ubuntu 22.04, using python.

I tried `av.open(format='alsa', file='default')` and `av.open(format='pulse', file='default')`, and got `ValueError: no container format 'alsa'.

So, what can I do to solve it?
Thank you

Comment: `av.open(format='alsa', file='default')` should have worked (I tried it and there is no error). According to the [following post](https://github.com/pupil-labs/pupil/issues/979) the issue is related to installation issues.

Comment: I made more researches, and got a solution:
`sudo apt-get install libavdevice-dev`
`pip3 uninstall av`
`pip3 install av --no-binary av`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
    def get_available_cameras(self):

        devices = FilterGraph().get_input_devices()

        available_cameras = {}

        for device_index, device_name in enumerate(devices):
            available_cameras[device_index] = device_name

        return available_cameras

    def create_local_tracks(self):
        global relay, webcam
        options = {"framerate": "30", "video_size": "640x480"}
        camera_name = "video="+self.get_available_cameras()[0]
        webcam = MediaPlayer(camera_name, format='dshow', options=options)
        relay = MediaRelay()
        return relay.subscribe(webcam.video)
```